Como borrar los filtros activos en una tabla en ANT DESING VUE
Tengo un problema quiero borrar los filtros de una tabla con un boton personalizado NO  el que trae la libreria el cual hace lo mismo que es borrar los datos o restablecer la tabla lo que quiero es que una vez darle click a ese boton que aparezca de nuevo los datos generales sin filtros.
intente de muchas maneras y segui un ejemplo de la documentacion pero no me funciona ya que borra el registro de los filtros pero me desactiva los filtros que trae mi tabla o sea no busca, ni filtra por fehcas tec.
     <BButton variant="danger" class="material-shadow-none"
                                                @click="restablecerFiltros()">
                                                <i class="ri-filter-2-line me-1 align-bottom"></i> Borrar filtros
                                            </BButton>

 const columnsSocios = [
       {
     title: "Numero",
     dataIndex: 'ID',
    key: "ID",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.ID - b.ID,
    customFilterDropdown: true,
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.ID.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownOpenChange: visible => {
        if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                searchInput.value.focus();
            }, 100);
        }
    },

  },
  {
    title: "Nombre",
    dataIndex: 'NombreCompleto',
    key: "NombreCompleto",
    customFilterDropdown: true,
    sorter: (a, b) => a.NombreCompleto - b.NombreCompleto,
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.NombreCompleto.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownOpenChange: visible => {
        if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                searchInput.value.focus();
            }, 100);
        }
    },
  },
  ];



      <a-table class="ant-table-striped" size="middle" :columns="filteredColumns"
                                :data-source="dataSocios" :row-class-name="alternateRowClass" bordered
                                :pagination="pagination" :loading="loading">

                                <template
                                    #customFilterDropdown="{ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters, column }">
                                    <div style="padding: 8px">
                                        <a-input ref="searchInput" :placeholder="`Buscar ${column.dataIndex}`"
                                            :value="selectedKeys[0]"
                                            style="width: 188px; margin-bottom: 8px; display: block"
                                            @change="e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])"
                                            @pressEnter="handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, column.dataIndex)" />
                                        <a-button type="primary" size="small" style="width: 90px; margin-right: 8px"
                                            @click="handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, column.dataIndex)">
                                            <template #icon>
                                                <SearchOutlined />
                                            </template>
                                            Buscar
                                        </a-button>
                                        <a-button size="small" style="width: 90px"
                                            @click="handleReset(clearFilters)">
                                            Borrar
                                        </a-button>
                                    </div>
                                </template>

                                <template #customFilterIcon="{ filtered }">
                                    <search-outlined :style="{ color: filtered ? '#108ee9' : undefined }" />
                                </template>

                                <template #bodyCell="{ column, record }">

                                    <template v-if="column.dataIndex === 'ID'">
                                        <span class="low fw-bolder">#{{ record.ID }}</span>
                                    </template>

                                    <template v-if="column.dataIndex === 'Nombre'">

                                    </template>
    </a-table>

